# Do we have any tool to identify which codes has been covered by an automation test class(e.g: fitnesse test)?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, code-coverage, jacoco, test-reporting

Currently, I am using jacoco report tool to know how much coverage for my system. But this system is quite old and has many existing Fitnesse tests. I am newbie on this system and want to learn it by reading its Fitnesse test. My problem is I dont know what Fitnesse test is for what specific class.Beside that When I see a class is covered and I dont know which Fitnesse test covered this class. My system has more than 500 Fitnesse Tests.

Answer (score 1):

JaCoCo [does not provide this out of the box](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/Qs9P5cyt58s/gzsBAP8qBgAJ).

There are some third-party JaCoCo integrations such as [SonarQube that allow to obtain information about relation between JUnit or TestNG test to code](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Usage+of+JaCoCo+with+Java+Plugin#UsageofJaCoCowithJavaPlugin-Coveragepertest). Don't know much about Fitnesse, so can't tell whether this will work with it or not.

However referring to the [same link](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/jacoco/Qs9P5cyt58s/gzsBAP8qBgAJ): general principle to obtain such information using JaCoCo (and that's how SonarQube does) - is to measure coverage separately for each test and save data into place dedicated to this test.

Also IDEs are able to show coverage (there are [EclEmma plugin for Eclipse](http://www.eclemma.org/) based on JaCoCo and other tools for other IDEs), so if you're able to run Fitneese test in IDE, then this principle can be applied even manually by running one test after another within IDE.

Also [have a look](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/Unit+Test+Results+and+Per-Test+Coverage) at another code coverage tool for Java that is commercial and named Clover.

Comment: Thanks alot for your huge information, Godin! I appreciate that.

Comment: @Tin if answer addresses question, then as a good StackOveflow citizen please don't forget to upvote/accept it